# Bootstrap 3 select input form inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-select

I'm trying to get input and select option inline attached with each other like [this demo using Bootstrap 2 (dead link)](http://bootply.com/93408).

Following Bootstrap 3 guidelines I manage to do this:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-7 pull-right well">
      <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="get">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" name="q">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
          <select class="form-control" name="category">
              <option>select</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3 pull-right" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's responsive, but input and select can't be attached without some nasty css hacks. I found lot of examples with attached buttons, but that does not work with select element.

Comment: They say "avoid using <select> elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers" :( Why throw native html element and use some css/js tricks to emulate it?

Comment: I also find that insane. And using ul li instead of select option makes getting the selected value rather awkward using javascript.

Answer (score 33):

I think I've accidentally found a solution. The only thing to do is inserting an empty `<span class="input-group-addon"></span>` between the `<input>` and the `<select>`.

Additionally you can make it "invisible" by reducing its width, horizontal padding and borders:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" title="* Price" id="priceLabel">Price</span>
    <input type="number" id="searchbygenerals_priceFrom" name="searchbygenerals[priceFrom]" required="required" class="form-control" value="0">
    <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
    <input type="number" id="searchbygenerals_priceTo" name="searchbygenerals[priceTo]" required="required" class="form-control" value="0">
  
    <!-- insert this line -->
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
  
    <select id="searchbygenerals_currency" name="searchbygenerals[currency]" class="form-control">
        <option value="1">HUF</option>
        <option value="2">EUR</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Tested on Chrome and FireFox.

Answer (score 16):

Can be done with pure Bootstrap code.

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id" class="col-md-2 control-label">ID</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <select class="form-control" name="id" id="id">
        <option value="">
      </select>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <select class="form-control" name="nr" id="nr">
        <option value="">
      </select>
    </span>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to make different size col-* for selects?

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to G_money and other suggestions for this excellent solution to input-text with inline dropdown...  here's another great solution.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="yourformID-form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-male"></i></span>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input size="50" maxlength="50" class="form-control" name="q" type="text">          
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="category">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="0">select1</option>
                <option value="1">select2</option>
                <option value="2">select3</option>
            </select>           
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This works with Bootstrap 3: allowing input-text inline with a select dropdown. Here's what it looks like below...

[image]

Comment: @KyleMit hmm.. it did before, but good find.  To fix this, I merged the `input text` and `select` into the same `form-group div`, and styled the form controls `width` to make it work.

Answer (score 9):

It requires a minor CSS addition to make it work with Bootstrap 3:

```css
.input-group-btn:last-child > .form-control {
  margin-left: -1px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <select class="form-control" name="category">
        <option>select</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I can't seem to make that work without hacks either, so what I did was just use the drop-down menu in place of a select box and send the info through a hidden field, like so (using your code):

http://bootply.com/93417

Jquery:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  var selected = $(this).text();
  $('.category').val(selected);  
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-7 pull-right well">
      <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="get">
        <div class="input-group col-sm-8">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" name="q">
       <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
         <input type="hidden" name="category" class="category">
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3 pull-right" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if that will work for what you want, but it is an option for you.

Comment: I think this is only solution in Boostrap 3 without using additional css, also documented http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns.

Comment: @Collector It doesnt work like a select. the selected option is not placed in the collapsed dropdown

Answer (score 3):

Another different answer to an old question. However, I found a  implementation made specifically for bootstrap which might prove useful here. Hope this helps anybody who is looking...

[Bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on spacebean's answer, this modification also changes the displayed text when the user selects a different item (just as a `<select>` would do):

http://www.bootply.com/VxVlaebtnL

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-7 pull-right well">
    <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="get">
      <div class="input-group col-sm-8">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" name="q">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span id="mydropdowndisplay">Choice 1</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="mydropdownmenu">
            <li><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Choice 3</a></li>
          </ul>
          <input type="hidden" id="mydropwodninput" name="category">
        </div><!-- /btn-group -->
      </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3 pull-right" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#mydropdownmenu > li').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var selected = $(this).text();
  $('#mydropwodninput').val(selected);
  $('#mydropdowndisplay').text(selected);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it without extra css or jquery:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="extra3">Extra name 3</label>
        <input type="text" id="extra3" class="form-control" placeholder="Extra name">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
               Mandatory? <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox5" value="option1">
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
             <label class="checkbox-inline">
               Per person? <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox6" value="option2">
             </label>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            To be paid? 
            <select>
                <option value="online">Online</option>
                <option value="on spot">On Spot</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a bit old, but I had the same problem and my search brought me here. I wanted two select elements and a button all inline, which worked in 2 but not 3. I ended up wrapping the three elements in `<form class="form-inline">...</form>`. This actually worked perfectly for me.