# Create a dropdown in a form element using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is what I am trying to do

[image]

So, I tried it using the following way

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div className="create-job-form-container">
    <form className="form-inline text-center" role="form">
        <div className="col-xs-4">
            <div className="form-group  col-xs-12">
                <label className="control-label">company/project</label>
                <select className="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-4">
            <div className="form-group  col-xs-12">
                <label>Select Technology</label>
                <select className="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-4">
            <div className="form-group  col-xs-12">
                <label>Job Description</label>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-info">Button</button>
                        Or
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-info">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

But there is a problem with the select elements and it is not coming properly. So, what am I doing wrong?

For this it's all in one row . SO I divided it in three parts .

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem with the dropdown. Is it that they are not in same line? In that case [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905166/bootstrap-3-select-input-form-inline).

Comment: Actually, That is also the issue and the when I Use select that time it is not coming in centre . It is attached to the border.

Answer (score 0):

```
Why did you used className instead of class, Html not support to className. 

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="create-job-form-container">
    <form class="form-inline text-center" role="form">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group  col-xs-12">
                <label class="control-label">company/project</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group  col-xs-12">
                <label>Select Technology</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group  col-xs-12">
                <label>Job Description</label>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
                        Or
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Its in react, SO I used

Comment: You have just changed the ClassName to class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Class in bootstrap `d-flex justify-content-around`. Refer the below link

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/  for more information.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="create-job-form-container">
    <form class="form-inline text-center " role="form">
    <div class="col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-around">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group  col-xs-12">
                <label class="control-label">company/project</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group  col-xs-12">
                <label>Select Technology</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group  col-xs-12">
                <label>Job Description</label>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
                        Or
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```